Numerically solve a system of two equations using fourth-order Runge-Kutta
I intend to solve the following system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{- \cos(v) \cos(u)bc+\sin(v)a}{cab} :=f(u, v, t) \\
\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{(\sin(v) \cos(u)bc+ \cos(v)a) \cot(u)}{bac}:= g(u, v, t)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The only thing that has occurred to me is to use a numerical approximation, specifically Runge-Kutta of fourth order (if you know of another way to solve this system I would also appreciate it), for this let's fix two initial parameters
$u(1)=1$ and $v(1)=1$.
Using fourth-order Runge-Kutta the order of the calculations (on the computer) will be:

Initialization:
$$
   t_0 = a, \quad u_0 = 1, \quad v_0 = 1, \quad N = 10, \quad h = \frac{1}{10}
   $$

Adjustments of each iteration:
\begin{align*}
   k_0 &= h f(u_i, v_i, t_i) \\
   l_0 &= h g(u_i, v_i, t_i) \\
   k_1 &= h f\left(u_i + \frac{1}{2}k_0, v_i + \frac{1}{2}l_0, t_i + \frac{1}{2}h\right) \\
   l_1 &= h g\left(u_i + \frac{1}{2}k_0, v_i + \frac{1}{2}l_0, t_i + \frac{1}{2}h\right) \\
   k_2 &= h f\left(u_i + \frac{1}{2}k_1, v_i + \frac{1}{2}l1, t_i + \frac{1}{2}h\right) \\
   l_2 &= h g\left(u_i + \frac{1}{2}k_1, v_i + \frac{1}{2}l1, t_i + \frac{1}{2}h\right) \\
   k_3 &= h f(u_i + k_2, v_i + l_2, t_i + h) \\
   l_3 &= h g(u_i + k_2, v_i + l_2, t_i + h) \\
   u_{i+1} &= u_i + \frac{1}{6}(k_0 + 2k_1 + 2k_2 + k_3) \\
   v_{i+1} &= v_i + \frac{1}{6}(l_0 + 2l_1 + 2l_2 + l_3) \\
   t_{i+1} &= t_i + h
   \end{align*}


A possible algorithm in matlab is summarized as follows
clc;                                               % Clears the screen
clear all;

h=0.1;                                             % step size
t = 0:h:1;                                         % Calculates upto y(1)
u = zeros(1,length(t)); 
v = zeros(1,length(t)); 
u(1) = 1;                                          % initial condition
v(1) = 1;                                          % initial condition

% Define the constants a, b, c before using them in the functions
a = 1;  % Example value, set this to your actual value
b = 1;  % Example value, set this to your actual value
c = 1;  % Example value, set this to your actual value

F_tuv = @(t,u,v) (-cos(u) * cos(t) * b * c + sin(t) * a) / (c * a * b);                                
G_tuv = @(t,u,v) ((sin(u) * cos(c) * b * c + cos(u) * a) * cot(t)) / (b * a * c);

for i=1:(length(t)-1)                              % calculation loop
    k_1 = F_tuv(t(i),u(i),v(i));
    L_1 = G_tuv(t(i),u(i),v(i));
    k_2 = F_tuv(t(i)+0.5*h,u(i)+0.5*h*k_1,v(i)+0.5*h*L_1);
    L_2 = G_tuv(t(i)+0.5*h,u(i)+0.5*h*k_1,v(i)+0.5*h*L_1);
    k_3 = F_tuv((t(i)+0.5*h),(u(i)+0.5*h*k_2),(v(i)+0.5*h*L_2));
    L_3 = G_tuv((t(i)+0.5*h),(u(i)+0.5*h*k_2),(v(i)+0.5*h*L_2));
    k_4 = F_tuv((t(i)+h),(u(i)+k_3*h),(v(i)+L_3*h));
    L_4 = G_tuv((t(i)+h),(u(i)+k_3*h),(v(i)+L_3*h));

    u(i+1) = u(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*h;  % main equation
    v(i+1) = v(i) + (1/6)*(L_1+2*L_2+2*L_3+L_4)*h;  % main equation
end

Next, I corrected the code a little bit and fixed the values of a, b and c and I get the following code

This approach is accurate?, I welcome any help.

Why don't you use the MATLAB solver like this MSE_Q4928488

This is not an answer, but also too long for a comment. I think the code is easier to read and debug if right from the start you assume that your problem is in the form $y' = f(t,y)$, with $y:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The RK4 steps can be applied to a vector function $f$, avoiding a duplication of all constants.
def RK4(f, t0, y0, h, n):
    sol = np.zeros((n,len(y0)))
    t = np.linspace(t0,t0+n*h,n)
    sol[0] = y0
    for i in range(1, n):
        k1 = f(t[i-1], sol[i-1])
        k2 = f(t[i-1]+h/2, sol[i-1]+k1*h/2)
        k3 = f(t[i-1]+h/2, sol[i-1]+k2*h/2)
        k4 = f(t[i-1]+h, sol[i-1]+k3*h)
        sol[i] = sol[i-1] + h*(k1 + 2*k2  + 2*k3 + k4)/6
    return t, sol
def f(t, y):
    a=1; b=1; c=1
    out = np.zeros((len(y)))
    u = y[0]; v = y[1]
    out[0] = (-np.cos(v)*np.cos(u)*b*c*np.sin(v)*a)/(a*b*c)
    out[1] = (np.sin(v)*np.cos(u)*b*c+np.cos(v)*a)*np.cos(u)/(np.sin(u)*a*b*c)
    return out


Thanks for your contribution, I have made a reply to this post where I apply your method, it would be very helpful if you could comment on it.

Overall it looks good, but you made a grave error in the details. You took the variable order $(u,v,t)$ in the declaration of the functions, but applied the updates/offsets as if the order were $(t,u,v)$. Obviously this mix-up will give wrong results.
Also, you have full flexibility in the variable names, so take the same letters $u,v,t$ as in the theory/mathematical analysis of the ODE, IVP, Cauchy problem. It also helps if you name your offsets for their variables, k1u, k1v etc. This stronger association will make errors more obvious.

Thanks for your contribution, that is, in the algorithm I should exchange the values of $u_i$ for the values of $t_i$, or how do I correct the order that you indicate? I do not see it clear, the same for the code in matlab I guess, although in the code in matlab declare $(x, y, z)$ and should be applied as $(z, x, y)$ I guess, is that right?

I guess that the error is located in the matlab code, because there is $u_{i+1}, v_{i+1}$ and (considering that in the code is $(x, y, z)$) I put in this $v_{i+1}, t_{i+1}$, is this what you mean? I do not see it clear.

The error is also in the formulas for the RK4 step. In the code, one can compare the declarations of f,g with the ODE statement to find that (x,y) is used there as (u,v) while the RK4 step indeed would be correct if (y,z) were (u,v) and x contained t. So fix one convention for the position of tand keep to it.

I have corrected both the algorithm and the code trying to solve what you mention, is it something like that what you are referring to, if not, can you give me a hand, I would be very grateful.

I certainly see something suspicious, because when I compile the $v$ values are not displayed correctly, I certainly don't know what is going on.

Now the code is structurally correct, but the implementations of F an G are not correctly transcribed from the mathematical formulas.

I have checked the code and yes, the expressions are wrongly transcribed, it should be something like this
F_tuv = @(t,u,v) (-cos(u) * cos(t) * b * c + sin(u) * a) / (c * a * b);
G_tuv = @(t,u,v) ((sin(u) * cos(t) * b * c + cos(u) * a) * cot(t)) / (b * a * c);
But the question arises, when I run the program the values of $v$ are not displayed correctly, while those of $u$ are, why is this?

This is still not correct, there is no $t$ in the original formulas. The code should now closely replicate the formulas as they are.

An application of PierreCare code may be:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def RK4(f, t0, y0, h, n, display=False):
    sol = np.zeros((n, len(y0)))
    t = np.linspace(t0, t0 + n * h, n)
    sol[0] = y0
    for i in range(1, n):
        k1 = f(t[i - 1], sol[i - 1])
        k2 = f(t[i - 1] + h / 2, sol[i - 1] + k1 * h / 2)
        k3 = f(t[i - 1] + h / 2, sol[i - 1] + k2 * h / 2)
        k4 = f(t[i - 1] + h, sol[i - 1] + k3 * h)
        sol[i] = sol[i - 1] + h * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6
    
    if display:
        plt.plot(t, sol)
        plt.xlabel('t')
        plt.ylabel('y')
        plt.legend([f'y{i}' for i in range(1, len(y0)+1)])
        plt.title('Solución utilizando RK4')
        plt.show()
    
    return t, sol

def f(t, y):
    a = 1; b = 1; c = 1
    out = np.zeros(len(y))
    u = y[0]; v = y[1]
    out[0] = (-np.cos(v) * np.cos(u) * b * c * np.sin(v) * a) / (a * b * c)
    out[1] = (np.sin(v) * np.cos(u) * b * c + np.cos(v) * a) * np.cos(u) / (np.sin(u) * a * b * c)
    return out


t0 = 0
y0 = [1, 1]  
h = 0.1
n = 100


t, sol = RK4(f, t0, y0, h, n, display=True)

Does it work?

There is a small mistake, coming from my post, in the definition of f. In out[0] you must change (...)* b * c * np.sin(...) to (...)* b * c + np.sin(...). Apart from that, I think it's ok.
